# How to use multiple where condition in codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I have to fetch the data from table using multiple where conditions in one table.I have tired so far but the results are not correct.

my code:

```
function Display(){
    $category = $this->input->post('dms_category_id');
    $subcategory =  $this->input->post('dms_subcategory_id');
    $docname = $this->input->post('dms_doc_name');
    $doctag = $this->input->post('dms_doc_tag');

    $startdate = $this->input->post('dms_start_date');
    $s_date = str_replace('/', '-', $startdate);
    $newstart = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($s_date));
    
    $enddate = $this->input->post('dms_end_date');
    $e_date = str_replace('/', '-', $enddate);
    $newend = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($e_date));

    
$data['documents']  = $this->db->query(
        "SELECT * 
        FROM `dms_document` as `D` 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `dms_category` as `C` ON `C`.`dms_category_id` = `D`.`dms_category_id` 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `dms_sub_category` as `S` ON `S`.`dms_subcategory_id` = `D`.`dms_subcategory_id` 
        WHERE D.`dms_doc_tag` LIKE '%$doctag%' ESCAPE '!' 
        OR `dms_doc_tag` IN('$doctag') 
        AND `dms_expire_date` >= '$newstart' 
        AND `dms_expire_date` <= '$newend' 
        OR D.`dms_doc_name` IN('docname') 
        OR `D`.`dms_category_id` IN('category') 
        OR `D`.`dms_subcategory_id` IN('$subcategory') 
        ORDER BY D.`dms_id` ASC")
    ->result_array();
$data['_view'] = 'dms_report/Report_List';
$this->load->view('layouts/main',$data);
```

please help me solve this problem.

my pic[image]

see this picture the last row also displaying ?

Comment: What has `phpMyAdmin` got to do with this question?

Comment: If you are using OR and AND in a WHERE clause you need to use brackets to make sure the correct logic will get applied

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have tired but i didn't got any correct answer

Comment: I have never come across `ESCAPE '!'` can someone explain

Comment: i used like variable that field1 has many value like php,doc,hello i have to search individual  values in them  and to display the data

Comment: @RiggsFolly  i updated my questions